# Overloading and LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list, operator-overloading, overloading, cout

I was trying to overload `cout` operator to print a class.

The class consists of an integer value and a pointer. So I was hoping to print an integer value and a memory address, but I got an error. I got confused since the class itself already has a pointer and couldn't figure out the problem.

The compiler gives "expected primary-expression before '.' token" error for the overloading part of the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
public:
    int Value;
    Node* Next;

};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, Node& head){

    a << "Value " << Node.Value << endl;
    a << "To where " << Node.Next << endl;
    return a;
}


int main()
{
    Node* head = new Node();
    Node* second = new Node();
    Node* third = new Node();

    head -> Value = 1;
    second -> Value = 2;
    third -> Value = 3;

    head -> Next = second;
    second -> Next = third;
    third -> Next = NULL;

    cout << head;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Node.value should be head.Value.  Same with Node.Next,  Also make the head argument const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, generally we need to add a **friend declaration** for the overloaded `operator<<` so that the be-friended function can access the private fields of the class type as shown below. But since both the data members of your class type are `public` you **can skip** the friend declaration.

**Second**, `Node.value` should be replaced by `head.value` as shown below.

**Third**, `cout << head` should be replaced by `cout << *head` as shown below:

```
class Node{
public:
    int Value;
    Node* Next;
    
    //friend declaration for overloaded operator<< NOTE: Since both the data members are public you can skip this friend declaration
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& a, const Node& head);

};
//definition for overloaded operator<<
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& a,const Node& head){

    a << "Value " << head.Value << std::endl << "To where " << head.Next;
    return a;
}
int main()
{
    Node* head = new Node();
    Node* second = new Node();
    Node* third = new Node();

    head -> Value = 1;
    second -> Value = 2;
    third -> Value = 3;

    head -> Next = second;
    second -> Next = third;
    third -> Next = NULL;

    std::cout << *head; 
    
    //don't forget to use delete to free the dynamic memory 

}
```

Also, don't forget to use `delete`(when/where needed) so that you don't have memory leaks.

Comment: "*you need to add a `friend` declaration for the overloaded `operator<<`*" - no, you don't, since the fields being printed are `public`. `friend` would be needed only if they were not `public`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes i have added a note saying that we can skip the friend declaration since both the data members are `public` in OP's case.